# Solspace Freeform {freeform:edit_data:status}

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace

Freeform 4.1.2

I'm attempting to edit the {freeform:edit_data:status} on the front-end of my site like  so:

```
{exp:freeform:edit
entry_id="{segment_3}"
form_name="referral_application"
notify_on_edit="yes"
restrict_edit_to_author="no"
return="/referrals#myreferrals/status_changed_success" 
}
 <select id="status" name="status">
   <option value="{freeform:edit_data:status}" selected>
    {freeform:edit_data:status}    
</option>
<option value="open">Approved</option>
 <option value="closed">Declined</option>

 </select>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="submit">

 {/exp:freeform:edit}
```

I saw post on Solspace that said it was going to be fixed in version 4.0.6 :
http://www.solspace.com/forums/viewthread/13266/#54728

Has anyone had any success with editing a status?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To edit the status on the front end, allow_status_edit="yes"  needs to be added to the exp:freeform:edit form.